# System verilog: check if logic signal changes at posedge

Tags: digital-logic, verilog, system-verilog

I'm relatively new to SV. I'm building a testbench in which I want to monitor a signal and take some action if it value changes @ clock posedge.
I’m looking for a compact way to this (I.e. not using a register).

```
logic [31:0] var_signal

Inizialmente
begin
  for(i=0; i<max_cles; i++) begin
      @(posedge clk_i);
      //check if var_signal changed and do something
  end
end
```

I searched the web and found threads on assertions but it is not what I want to do here.
Any hints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to monitor a signal and take some action if it value changes @ clock posedge.

I know you don't want to use a register but it can be test-bench register. You have to make a copy at the clock edge and compare it against the old value:

```
logic [31:0] new_var_signal
always @(posedge clk_i)
   new_var_signal <= var_signal;

assign signal_changed_at_clock_edge = (new_var_signal != var_signal) ? 1 : 0;
```

There is a caveat: if the signal can also become 'z' or 'x' you should use:

```
assign signal_changed_at_clock_edge = (new_var_signal !== var_signal) ? 1 : 0;
```

Note that you are in an ideal simulation environment and there is no such moment as `@(posedge..` That moment is infinitely short.

In a real digital design the signal has to be stable around the clock edge. The time before the clock edge is called the *setup* time and the time after is called the *hold* time.

Comment: How do I detect if a two signals toggled in same verilog queuing window? i.e error if two signals toggled in active window or error if two signals toggled in nba window